# Understanding algorithm for finding the smallest circle enclosing points

Tags: algorithm

At the moment I try to learn and understand geometric algorithms and I found the smallest-circle-problem quite interesting. I found many solutions and different algorithms including [this one](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides4b.pdf) of which I'm not sure if it is Emo Welzl's.

However, I don't understand **one specific** (important) part:

1. You're given N points on a (XY)-Plane.
2. You order those points randomly
3. Choose 3 points and create the circle where they are on the circle boundary.
4. Get the next point and check if it is enclosed by the circle:

   a) If it is enclosed, repeat 4 until there are no more points left.

   b) If is not enclosed, create a new circle where the new point is on the circle boundary and still all other points are inside or on the circle.

Steps 1) to 4a) are simple, my problem is step 4b). How can I find this new circle? To me, it seems like this is the same problem just with a smaller (sub)set of points. (Divide-et-Impera)

I guessed I have to replace one of the 3 original points (the first 3 points, that made up the first circle) with the new point, but I'm not sure
if this really works...

Answer (score 1):

From the 3 points A,B,C you can calculate the centre O of the circle: the point that is equidistant to those three. Its coordinates xO and yO are the means of xA,xB,xC and yA, yB, yC respectively.

Let's call D the 4th point, trace the circle of centre 0 and radius OD.

OD > OA (and OA=OB=OC) so A, B and C are in the circle.

#### EDIT

The solution I proposed above is not optimal.

I found a good explanation of Welzl's algorithm: [see link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/welzl-r2484)

Of course, you can get his paper easily by looking on Google Scholar, but it is quite hard to read.

The basic principle is that in 4b) the circle is computed from all the possible circles having D on the boundary as well as two other points that were on the boundary before (or one point if that doesn't work and it will be diametrically opposed to D).

Comment: But it's not necessarily the smallest circle that encloses `A, B, C and D`.

Comment: sorry, I misread. Find the centroid of A,B,C,D then trace the circle that encloses them all then. The algorithm is not very clear on that, I agree.

Comment: I agree with Dese on the fact that his answer does exactly what the algorithim describes. But I doubt that the algorithm itself returns the SMALLEST circle for the givven points. Just assume, the given points A,B and C are quite close together and point D is far away: maybe 10 times the diameter of the circle around A,B and C. Try to sketch it and you will see that the circle you end up with wont be the smallest one enclosing all four points.

Comment: EDIT on my previous comment : if that worked, you could do it directly for the n points... checking and coming back after !
I agree with you Stefan, the algorithm doesn't seem really efficient. Or at least incomplete, as OP said: it is the same problem, but with less points.

Comment: The explanation at GameDev accessible through your link is definitely NOT the Welzl's algorithm. It appears to be a naive simplification of Welzl's approach. And, expectedly, the algorithm at the link is completely incorrect. The author of the GameDev algorithm apparently believed that once some point exits the set of *supporting points* it can never become a supporting point again. However, it is easy to demonstrate that this is not true. This is exactly why the true Welzl's algorithm has a more complicated recursive internal structure.